New probable prime test for $m = 2^n + k$ (potentially rigorous for certain $k$)
Let $m = 2^n + k$, with $n$ odd, $k < 2^n$ and $k$ odd.  Assume $n$ is invertible modulo $m-1$.
Let $e = n^{-1} \mod (m-1)$.
If $m$ is prime then $(-k)^e \equiv 2 \pmod{m}$.
However some composites can also pass this test.
But the composites that pass this test tend to have large $k$ (relative to $n$), while the primes that pass the test can have the typical $k$ we might expect by the PNT for primes close to $2^n$, i.e. $k = O(n)$.
If we also require $m$ is a strong pseudoprime to base $k$, i.e. $k^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, empirically it seems to hold that if $m$ is a composite that passes the $n$-th root test described above, we always have $k > \sqrt{m}$.
Is there any hope of proving this?  This is an open-ended question, but is it at least possible to say what kind of methods might be brought to bear on a potential proof?
The motivation is that this might give a new rigorous primality test (for $k < \sqrt{m}$), not just a probable prime test.
It is likely that the requirement that $m$ be a strong pseudoprime to base $k$ can be dropped, for "$m$ sufficiently large".
[EDIT] The question in its original form above was closed for the following reason: "Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.".
A new rigorous primality test for a large class of numbers would be extremely relevant to the mathematics community, especially computational number theorists.  This question sets a clearly specified target property which if proved would give such a test, and would be a significant breakthrough.  I tried to prove a special case using the explicit Chinese Remainder Theorem as follows:
Suppose $m = pq$ is an odd composite.  Since $k\equiv -2^n \pmod{m}$, we have $k\equiv -2^n \pmod{p}$ and $k\equiv -2^n \pmod{q}$.  With the explicit CRT, we can write
$k = p(-2^np^{-1} \mod{q}) + q(-2^nq^{-1} \mod{p}) - \delta pq$
where $\delta \in {0,1}$.  We have to show $k > \sqrt{m}$.  If $\delta = 0$ there is nothing to show, since the congruences have positive representatives and either $p$ or $q$ is greater than $\sqrt{m}$.  So we are left with the case $\delta = 1$.
We can consider the inequality $k > \sqrt{pq}$, square both sides and see if it can be proved to hold.  Let $Q = -2^np^{-1} \mod{q}$ and $P = -2^nq^{-1} \mod{p}$.
We end up with trying to determine whether
$p^2Q^2+q^2P^2+2pQqP+p^2q^2 > pq +2pq(pQ+qP)$.
Although this appears to be true empirically (just as the test predicts), it seems difficult to make any argument with $P$,$Q$ which probably behave like random numbers modulo $p$,$q$ resp.  My reason for asking this question is to see if the community would have in mind alternative strategies to prove the test works, i.e. that this property of numbers close to $2^n$ is true for all integers under the hypotheses.
[EDIT2] The reason for not reopening the question is nonspecific.  I will leave the question and not delete it, even though it is closed, for the record.

This is not clear.  Perhaps working some examples would help.  What's the exponent?  Is it the inverse of $n\pmod {m-1}$?  But why should $\gcd(n,m-1)=1$?  For instance, with $m=7$ we have $n=2$ so $\gcd(n,m-1)=2$.   But perhaps you meant something entirely different?

I did specify $n$ odd, but you are right, I should have required that $\gcd{(n,m-1)}=1$ (will edit the question), yes the exponent is the inverse of $n \pmod{m-1}$.  For a random example, $m = 2^{31} + 260393$, and for $n=31$, this is the smallest $k$ for which composite $m$ passes the test, and here $k > \sqrt{m}$.

So, this is a weirdly specific primality test, then.

Yes but the range of numbers covered from $m$ to $m + \sqrt{m}$ is potentially large for large $m$, $\it{much}$ less specific than e.g. the LL test for 2^p-1.

I should really say the useful range covered is from $2^n$ to $2^n+2^{n-1}$, not "$m$ to $m+\sqrt{m}$".

Unless I'm calculating wrong, I don't think it's correct to say "if $m$ is prime then $(-k)^m \equiv 2 \pmod{m}$". For instance, $m=41$ seems to pass the criteria for inclusion but doesn't satisfy this.

And plenty of primes seem to have $k>\sqrt{m}$; eg $43$, $47$, $53$, $59$, $149$, $151$. Just testing up to $n=11$ it's pretty rare to have $k<\sqrt{m}$.

For $m=41$ we have $n=5,k=9$, i.e. $41 = 2^5+9$ and $\gcd{(n,m-1)} = 5$ so this is not covered in the setup (we require $\gcd{(n,m-1)} = 1$).  So to clarify, $m$ is the number we want to test for primality, and $n$, $k$ are such that $m = 2^n+k$.

Also I should emphasise that if it is rare/impossible that $k<\sqrt{m}$ for composite $m$ that's what we would like, because then we have a rigorous primality test for any $m$ in $[2^n+1,2^n+2^{n-1}-1]$ (under the hypotheses).  Also, eventually for $n$ increasing there will be lots of primes with $k = O(n)$ by the PNT.

Ah, my mistake with $41$! How high have you checked to see if any composite numbers satisfy $k<\sqrt{m}$?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
